# Fix a MapView above a scrollable TableViewCell in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get my MapView fixed on top of a list where people can scroll through. I can't find a way to keep the MapView on the iPhone screen while scrolling down in the list.

[image: This is the structure of my TableViewController]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't add your MapView to the UITableView.  Add it to the ViewController.view as a peer to the TableView and use constraints to set the relative sizes.